# vpn ssh android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, ssh, vpn

I am trying to create a program that can connect to vps through ssh and use it as a vpn on mobile, but nothing happens when I click on the button.

```
  private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    
    
    private var isTunnelActive = false
    private lateinit var session: Session
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    
        binding.connectionButton.setOnClickListener {
            if (!isTunnelActive) {
                establishTunnel()
                binding.connectionButton.text = "Disconnect"
            } else {
                closeTunnel()
                binding.connectionButton.text = "Connect"
            }
            isTunnelActive = !isTunnelActive
        }
    }
    
    private fun establishTunnel() {
        Thread {
            val jsch = JSch()
            session = jsch.getSession("root", "11.11.111.111", 22)
            session.setPassword("mmmmmmmmmm")
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no")
            session.connect()
    
            session.setPortForwardingL(0, "111.11.11.11", 22)
        }.start()
    }
    
    private fun closeTunnel() {
        session.disconnect()
    }
```

and i use

````
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE"         tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />```


`i want some one help me in this project please`
````

I need a code with which I can use vps as vpn like napsternetv apps